# Compare contents of 2 tables with same column names and insert/update on the basis of primary key in Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql

I have currently written the logic in MYSQL using python and it's working without any errors. I am trying to replicate the same on POSTGRESQL. Please find the code below:

MYSQL CODE

```
db_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1=VALUES(col1), col2=VALUES(col2)")
```

POSTGRESQL CODE

```
db_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1=SELECT(col1), col2=SELECT(col2)")
```

I am getting the following error while trying to execute the POSTGRESQL code:

```
TypeError: function missing required argument 'vars_list' (pos 2)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the _complete_ error traceback, and tag the question with the package that you are using for the database connection.

Comment: @Rajat can you share python code. Manly function where this code is written.